# What is the pattern in this set {2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, ...}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find a way to define this set in set-builder notation but it doesn't seem possible. I ran it by 2 other people who were well versed in math and they couldn't see a discernible pattern either.

Comment: Please read over the tag descriptions before using them. As the tag description for [proof-theory] explains, it is not appropriate for this question.

Comment: If there is 2 at the beginning, I would guess it is the sequence of numbers which only have factors 2 and 3.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin no it wouldn't. 15 has factor 5.

Comment: Other than 1 and 2, those are exactly the numbers that have the form $2^i3^j$.

Comment: @79037662: Duh me....

Comment: Sorry I accidentally deleted the 2 when I submitted

Answer (score 4):

3-smooth numbers: numbers of the form $2^i 3^j$ with $i, j \geq 0$.

[OEIS A003586](http://oeis.org/A003586)

Comment: But with $i,j=0$ you will have $1$, $2$ also in the set.

Comment: OK, then $i \ge 2$ or $j \ge 1$.

Comment: @RobPratt But then 9 or 8 respectively would not be in the set. Perhaps say "$i$ and $j$ not both 0$.

Comment: 9 has $i=0$ and $j=2$, and 8 has $i=3$ and $j=2$.  In both cases, $i \ge 2$ or $j \ge 1$.  Your proposed condition allows $i=1$ and $j=0$, which we want to exclude.

Comment: What is the relation with Pythagoras btw? Don't see any mention in OEIS, apart from a mention on Harmonic numbers (which could be related since Pythagoras was into music too and the image does show bells etc.) - https://antikleidi.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Gaffurio_Pythagoras.png

Comment: ...just noticed the last quadrant of that image mentioning Philolaus (Φιλόλαος, friend of the people in Greek), and searching on his name found wikipedia article with a part from that same image - seems he was astronomer related to Pythagoras and number theory https://el.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A6%CE%B9%CE%BB%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%BF%CF%82

Comment: Seems the original image is about Pythagoras Tuning and is from an old music book. I now see more clearly that in the first quadrant too that also has the same numbers they play music, hitting something with hammers -  https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gaffurio_Pythagoras.png https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pythagoras_and_Philolaus.png

Comment: In OEIS Sloane who comments that the numbers were once called Harmonic points to some Lenstra talk that is related to a lemma proof by Gersonides and the abc-conjecture. Sounds interesting to follow up...

Comment: Speaking of Pythagoras, it seems he considered 1,2,3 as generator numbers, probably that's why the numbers in the image that had captured my interest start from 4. E.g. 2 was for female, 3 for male and 2*3=6 was for their marriage was mentioned at the article on the theology/philosophy on everything being mirrors of numbers behind Pythagoras' mathematics - https://antikleidi.com/2015/02/08/aritmoi-pithagoras/ (article in Greek)

Comment: ...out of chance I found the answer about the hamers and the anvil in the 1st quadrant of that medieval image I had mentioned above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKaufPZ9UhQ&t=559 - it's the story that Pythagoras got inspired regarding notes by hearing hammers hit an anvil passing by a blacksmith's

Answer (score 0):

Integers of the form $n=\frac{144}k$ with $k\le 50$.